# No suitable method found for add() in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, methods, addition, gridpane

I try to add a borderpane in my gridpane with the method add() like that :

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.getChildren().add(new BorderPane());
grid.getChildren().add(new BorderPane(), 1, 0); // ERROR HERE
```

But I receive this error :

> error: no suitable method found for add(BorderPane,int,int)
>               grid.getChildren().add(new BorderPane(), 1, 0); 
>       method Collection.add(Node) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       method List.add(Node) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       method List.add(int,Node) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   Note: C:\Users\OFN\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CryptionTest\src\fr\cryption\control\ExplorerPage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I searched for three hours on Google and Stackoverflow but there is no solution for my problem.

Here is the imports I used :

```
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: To help people give you an aswer, I believe you should post the error you get and a minimum working example.

Comment: `ObservableList` doesn't have an `add(Node, int, int)` method (or any method that accepts parameters that can be automatically case from that). Perhaps you mean `grid.add(...)`?

Comment: I edited the post with the message sorry.

Comment: Damn, James_D you find the solution !! I deleted the getChildren() and it works ! What a noob I am.. Thank you, but i'm a little surprised that getChildren() is not allowed.

Comment: @OFFEN: Why are you surprised? `getChildren()` is defined in `Pane` which does not use any layout parameters. Row/column index only makes sense for a layout like `GridPane`. It wouldn't make any sense for e.g. `FlowPane`. Those `add` methods of `GridPane` are only convenience methods for assigning the layout parameters and adding the child using a single method call. You could add the children to the list yourself but in that case you need to set the layout parameters yourself: `GridPane.setRowIndex(c, 1); GridPane.setColumnIndex(c, 2); grid.getChildren().add(c);`

Comment: @fabian I saw this method in an example of a tutorial and I thought it could work with all containers (get child of Gridpane doesn't shock me). Moreover, it works without parameters so it was disturbing. But I keep in mind your message I need to train a lot again. Thanks.

Comment: `getChildren()` returns an `ObservableList`, so its add method is defined by `List` interface. `Gridpane` defined its own add method, and internally it calls the add method of the list. There is nothing confusing here.